# EF code first enforce two classes not have the same foreign key instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have this model:

```
public class A
{
      public int Id{get;set;} 
      public string Name{get;set;}     
}

public class B
{
      public int Id{get;set;} 
      public string Name{get;set;}   
      public virtual A Instance{get;set;}  
}

public class C
{
      public int Id{get;set;} 
      public string Name{get;set;}  
      public virtual A Instance{get;set;}     
}
```

I want that if for example I have instance A with name "MyInstance" that only one B or C class can have reference to it and if someone else try to reference "MyInstance" the code will throw exception.
How can I configure it?

Answer (score 1):

Such constraint can't be defined in the EF. You need to enforce the constraint in your code.

One possible solution:

```
public class A {
    private B _referenceB;
    private C _referenceC;

    public int Id { get; set; } 

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual B ReferenceB {
        get { return _referenceB; }
        set { 
                if (this.ReferenceC != null) {
                   throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
                _referenceB = value;
            }
        }

    public virtual C ReferenceC {
        get { return _referenceC; }
        set { 
                if (this.ReferenceB != null) {
                   throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
                _referenceC = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternative solution:

```
public class ReferenceBase { }
public class B : ReferenceBase { ... }
public class C : ReferenceBase { ... }
public class A {
    public virtual ReferenceBase  Reference { get; set; }
    //implement a custom setter if you want to throw exception
}
```

Comment: This is a solution but if I have not just B and C, if I have 10 classes that can reference A it is a bit problem no?

Comment: Yes, with more classes it gets impractical. Alternative solution would be to derive `B` and `C` from the same base class and define a relationship between `A` and the base class.